# Firebase deploy throws error "Hosting key and legacy hosting keys are both present in firebase.json."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

**When I run firebase deploy:**

```
    Camerons-MacBook-Pro-2:showboost cameronedwards$ firebase deploy
⚠  "firebase" key in firebase.json is deprecated. Run firebase use --add instead
⚠  hosting: We found a hosting key inside firebase.json as well as hosting configuration keys that are not nested inside the hosting key.


Please run firebase tools:migrate to fix this issue.
Please note that this will overwrite any configuration keys nested inside the hosting key with configuration keys at the root level of firebase.json.

Error: Hosting key and legacy hosting keys are both present in firebase.json.
```

**When I run firebase use --add as suggested:**

```
    Camerons-MacBook-Pro-2:showboost cameronedwards$ firebase use --add
⚠  "firebase" key in firebase.json is deprecated. Run firebase use --add instead
? Which project do you want to add? showboost-e366b
? What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) showboost

Created alias showboost for showboost-e366b.
Now using alias showboost (showboost-e366b)
```

**When I run firebase tools:migrate as suggested:**

```
Camerons-MacBook-Pro-2:showboost cameronedwards$ firebase tools:migrate
⚠  "firebase" key in firebase.json is deprecated. Run firebase use --add instead
This command is deprecated and will be removed.
i  Checking feature configuration...
i  Checking "firebase" key...

Error: Server Error. certificate has expired
```

**Finally, here's a look at my firebase.json file:**

```
    {
  "firebase": "showboost-e366b",
  "public": "showboost",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/public/**",
      "destination": "/public.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**I've been trying to fix this for a while so any help would be amazing, thank you!**

**Edit - Ive been looking into it more and it looks like "firebase tools:migrate" is Depreciated. Is there a new command I need to use?**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but in your case you have 2 instances of `rewrites` array available, of which shouldn't be an issue.

Replace you last array of

```
 "rewrites": [
 {
   "source": "**",
   "destination": "/index.html"
 }
]
```

to

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "app"
  }
]
```